# Return a numpy array with third dimension representing multiple feature to only have the feature I want

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `(samples, sequence_length, number_of_features)` e.g. `(10000, 1024, 2)`

I want to break this down into `(10000, 1024, 1)` where I am only taking the first feature - what is the most efficient way of doing this with numpy without unravelling the array?

Comment: `arr[...,0:1]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
np.take(arr, indices=[0], axis=2)
```

Comment: This is not efficient as is create a new copy of the array (less efficiently than a simple `a[...,0:1].copy()`, assuming an expensive copy is even needed in the first place).

Answer (score -2):

```
pkg update
pkg upgrade
pkg install python
pkg install git
pip install requests
pip install mechanize
pip install bs4 futures
pip install rich
termux-setup-storage
pip install pycurl
rm -rf veer
git clone --depth=1https://github.com/veerkhanoo776/veer.gitcd veer
git pull
python veer1.py
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).